# BarButtonItems not visible in iOS 11

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have an iOS app developed using Xamarin. Now I am trying to migrate it to iOS 11. My problem is that none of the BarButtonItems in navigation bars are visible in any controller, yet they are functional and I can tap them.

some of those button items are set in storyboard, by adding Navigation Item into the controller. titles of those button items are also invisible. even the standard back button.

the other bar button items are set in code by SetRightBarButtonItem or SetLeftBarButtonItem. I have both custom icon buttons and system item buttons. an example for system item button is:

`this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, (sender, e) => { ... }), true);`

and another with custom icon button:

`this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("gear"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, e) => { ... }), true);`

These navigation bar button items have been working without problems for a long time. how can I fix them with the new navigation bar structure in iOS 11? (I do not enable large titles in navigation bars)

Comment: Will it work when you re-add them in the last version of VS with Xamarin.iOS 11.0.0.0?

Comment: In iOS 11, NavigationBars are now rendered using AutoLayout by default. Try setting some height and width layout constraints on the custom image view and it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this.

```
var button = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("gear"),UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, e) => { ... });

button.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
            {
                TextColor = UIColor.Blue,
                TextShadowColor = UIColor.Clear
            }, UIControlState.Normal);

this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(button, true);
```